# Apple Push Notifications are not working in production with django-push-notifications

Tags: ios, django, notifications, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

I am using Django as my backend and front end iOS. I used `django-push-notifications` for sending push notification to iOS devices. I used proper certificate for this circumstances, which I test from my local (with production certificate) and gained the perfect result. However from my production server notifications are not sent.

Any help are cordially accepted.

Comment: Fortunately my production server is behaving fine.

Now I need to share my experience regarding this issue and that is, right after sending the Push Notification to Apple server I triggered for its feedback and log it as well. After doing this, Push Notification suddenly behaves as expected.

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately my production server is behaving fine. Now I need to share my experience regarding this issue and that is, right after sending the Push Notification to Apple server I triggered for its feedback and log it as well. After doing this, Push Notification suddenly behaves as expected. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Can you please add more details of the solution?

Comment: After sending APNS with `apns_devices_list.send_message`, I checked any inactive ids has found or not with `apns_fetch_inactive_ids` method. That's it.